# MFP CLI 7.1 creating android project target 23 , how to change that?

Tags: mobilefirst-cli

I have recently downloaded and installed mfp cli 7.1.0.00.20170120-0106. Ever since I did that mfp cli is creating an Android project targeting API level 23. I need it target API level 22. As it created a project targeting level 23 the Android project is giving me a compilation error as the compile SDK is set to 22. I tried to change it to 23 and it got rid of the compilation error but I am left with a non-functional app, because our app works best with API level 22. I need to know how to make mfp cli make an Android app targeting version 22.

Answer (score 0):

There is no feature in the CLI to change the template prokedg created by the CLI.

Options:

1. After building in the CLI, open in Android Studio and change it manaually
2. Create a script to run after the build command to do the same (modify a file)